# Sudden rise in temperature of new hard drive

Tags: backup, hard-drive, temperature

I recently (about two weeks ago) got a new hard drive for backups. It's a 3TB WD Green drive and operates externally, in a separate enclosure, connected via eSATA to my Linux home server.

What I'm concerned about is a sudden rise yesterday in its temperature, from about 37C to 40-41C. There was no disk activity at all at the time. I have a graph of it here:

[image]

The red line indicates the temperature of the internal system hard drive (the only hard drive inside the computer), while the blue line is the external backup hard drive.

Should I be concerned about this? Obviously the drive hasn't failed, but this seems like a sign that it isn't totally reliable.

Comment: Looks like a sign to me that something is keeping is spinning.  Either that or the clutter of papers around it has gotten too deep.

Comment: It's strange because it has suddenly gone down to its normal level since. There are no papers or anything around it; it's exposed (although the airflow is not good in the room). It could be that something was keeping it spinning as you say, because when I was doing a manual backup it was hovering around the 41C mark while in constant use.

Comment: You know, the simplest solution to your problem is to not look at the drive temperature.

Comment: Simple and totally ineffective :)

Comment: Your drive will be just as reliable if you don't look at the temperature.  The Heisenberg effect isn't *that* strong.

Comment: True, but I won't know if it's about to fail until it actually fails...

Comment: Trust me, something else will fail first.

Comment: I've already had one disk fail in this server, and that was new.